# Transfert files directly from remote url to S3 Bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services

I’m using a service who provide many .gz files and I want to transfer them to my S3 bucket. The client update these files every day. I have to stay in sync with his server and my S3 Bucket.

They provide an API with all endpoints where these files are stored.

```
{
fileName: "xxxxx",
url: "https://domaine.com/file.gz"
}
```

The idea is to create an Lambda (called every day) who would be in charge to transfer these .gz files directly from his server to my Bucket.

I’ve no idea how to do that.

Do you have articles or documentation about this use case?

Comment: I would actually not use Lambda since your're simply calling an API and uploading to your S3 bucket. This would incur unnecessary AWS costs. I would instead create a cron script that uses a combination of CURL and the [AWS CLI](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/) using your language of choice.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, what I did was pretty simple... I created an EC2 Ubuntu instance on which I run a bash script that I tweaked... This script is in charge of downloading the feed, parsing the URLs and downloading the file corresponding to each URL.

```
wget -O feed.csv https://feed.com/datafeed/list/apikey/xxx
IFS=','
while read f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 f6 f7 f8 f9 f10 f11 f12 f13; do
if [[ $f4 =~ "active" ]]; then
echo "remove quote from url..."
url="${f12%\"}"
url="${url#\"}"
echo "remove quote from id..."
name="${f5%\"}"
name="${name#\"}"
echo "download from url...${name}"
wget -O "${name}".csv.gz "${url}"
echo "upload to S3 from url...${name}"
aws s3 cp "${name}".csv.gz s3://mybucket/data/

fi
done < feed.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a very google-able question, I'll provide a quick lambda I put together for virus testing. If you want to use this, please change the URL that downloads a file.

This lambda is working for Python 3.10.

Set the environment variable to your bucket name: `DESTINATION_BUCKET_NAME`

```
import logging
import os
import json
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
import urllib.request
from datetime import datetime

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

s3_client = boto3.client("s3")

DESTINATION_BUCKET_NAME = os.environ['DESTINATION_BUCKET_NAME']

def handler(event, context):

    #===================================================================
    # NOTE. THIS LAMBDA INTENTIONALLY LOADS A MALWARE-INFECTED FILE.
    #===================================================================
    # Please do NOT deploy this to a production environment where security is a concern.

    virus_url = 'https://secure.eicar.org/eicar.com.txt'

    file_name = "/tmp/bad-file.txt"

    urllib.request.urlretrieve(virus_url, file_name)

    try:
        response = s3_client.upload_file(file_name, DESTINATION_BUCKET_NAME, f"eicar-virus-{datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S')}")
    except ClientError as e:
        logging.error(e)
        return {
            'StatusCode': 500
        }

    return {
        'StatusCode': 200,
        'Body': json.dumps(response)
    }
```